# RecyclerView is null

Tags: android

The main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        pAdapter = new ProductAdapter(productList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }
```

I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.co.thehawker.thehawker/in.co.thehawker.thehawker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at in.co.thehawker.thehawker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I cleaned and built the project, but problem remains the same. Is there some issue with activity_main layout as I have defined the recycler_view in content_main.xml? Please help!!!

Edited:
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml

Comment: content_main.xml is not inlcuded in activity_main.xml. Hence the recyclerview cannot be initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RecyclerView` is not in `activity_main.xml` so `findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)` can not find it. Inflate `content_main.xml` as `view` and try like this `view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Option1: Please check productList, did it init?
Option2: Check ProductAdapter.
```